# log4j first line was not shown in proper alignment

Tags: log4j

I am facing some problem regarding log message.
When I generate log report, the first line was not shown in proper alignment but rest of the log message was in proper order. 
I checked log patterns, but didn't find any clue to the issue.

Can anybody suggest me the how I can resolve this issue?

**Output:**

```
INFO|------------------------------- Start Control Information --------------------------    
  INFO|***********                                                                           
  INFO|**********************                                                        
  INFO|*****  ************************                                           
  INFO|Doc***** Version :  6.7.0004.0217  Win64.SQLServer                                
  INFO|------------------------------ End Control Information -----------------------------
  INFO|                                                                                              
  INFO|******************                                                              
  INFO|*************** :                                                                   
  INFO|Version identifiers :                                                                     
  INFO|***********

here , first line(INFO|------------------------------- Start Control Information --------------------------
```

Only the first line is not properly aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logger messages are generated based on the pattern layout of log4j.properties. If you wanted to do alignmnet of your logger message, you have use pattern layout as follows.

```
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA
    log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```